# Passing different form data entries to the same row in a database with Python Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I've created a form which takes user's name and their email address. I get this data from the form and put it into a sqlite3 database in the following way:

```
 @app.route('/my_form', methods=["GET", "POST"])

def form_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.form["name"]
        new_user = form_database(name=user_name)
        user_email = request.form["email"]
        new_user_email = form_database(email=user_email)
     try:
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.add(new_user_email)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect("/my_form")
```

**Current result**: each data entry gets recorded into a new row:

```
1|Jack||||||||||
2||svisto@hotmail.com|||||||||
```

**Desirable result**: each data entry gets recorded into the same row:

```
1|Jack|svisto@hotmail.com|||||||||
```

**Question:** How can I change the code such that I get the desirable result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution I found:**

I fused:

```
new_user = form_database(name=user_name) and new_user_email = form_database(email=user_email)
```

together such that the code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/my_form', methods=["GET", "POST"])

def form_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.form["name"]
        user_email = request.form["email"]
        new_user_details = form_database(name=user_name, email=user_email)#assigns 2 form inputs for both columns in the database model to the same variable
     try:
            db.session.add(new_user_details)#adds that variable to the database as one entry, hence in one row but different columns
            db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a User class in your model like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):    
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                   primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32),
                         index=False,
                         unique=True,
                         nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64),
                      index=True,
                      unique=True,
                      nullable=False)
```

Then you can do this in your try block

```
try:
    new_user = User(user_name=user_name,
                            email=email)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'll consider it for educational purposes and as an alternative.